# Python -- Max retries exceeded with url error while running the code

Tags: python-3.x

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /microsoft/qlib/main/scripts/get_data.py (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)')))

[image: My codes:]

Comment: Don't an 'https' endpoint require some authorization?

Comment: 'Don't an 'https' endpoint require some authorization?' Ok, I fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Don't an 'https' endpoint require some authorization?' Should have an authorization.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).